# 301 Redirecting Root Files

Tags: file, .htaccess, redirect

I'm having issues with files in my root folder *as well as* files with the same name in the sub-folders being redirected. Here's my htaccess file:

```
rewriteengine on

rewritecond %{http_host} ^mydomain.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]

redirect 301 /newsletters/ http://www.mydomain.com
redirect 301 /sample.html http://www.mydomain.com
```

The folder redirect works fine, but sample.html will redirect (great!) but so will /folder/sample.html /randomfolder/folder/sample.html and so on (not so great).

Any ideas? I've tried just using sample.html without the slash prefix but it simply doesn't redirect at that point.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) directive with a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). Start with a `^` to only match the start of the string.

```
RewriteRule ^sample.html$ http://www.mydomain.com
```